# Setting Minimum iOS Version number in Titanium Studio

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

How can we set minimum iOS version in **Appcelerator Titanium Studio** from default **4.3**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following setting to the `tiapp.xml`. Make sure to change `6.1` to whatever minimum iOS version you want to build your app for.

```
<ios>
    <min-ios-ver>6.1</min-ios-ver>
</ios>
```

`builder.py` looks at this value to decide what minimum version to build the project with. You can find builder.py at following location:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/<Titanium-SDK-Version>/iphone/builder.py
```

Don't forget to substitute `<Titanium-SDK-Version>` with your Titanium SDK version.